# Code: Code isn't working to sort through a list of 1 million integers, printing top 10

Tags: python, list, selection

This is for homework, so I must try to use as little python functions as possible, but still allow for a computer to process a list of 1 million numbers efficiently.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

#Find the 10 largest integers
#Don't store the whole list

import sys
import heapq

def fOpen(fname):
        try:
                fd = open(fname,"r")
        except:
                print("Couldn't open file.")
                sys.exit(0)
        all = fd.read().splitlines()
        fd.close()
        return all

words = fOpen(sys.argv[1])

numbs = map(int,words)
print(heapq.nlargest(10,numbs))

li=[]
count = 1



#Make the list
for x in words:
        li.append(int(x))
        count += 1
        if len(li) == 10:
                break


#Selection sort, largest-to-smallest
for each in range(0,len(li)-1):
        pos = each
        for x in range(each+1,10):
                if li[x] > li[pos]:
                        pos = x
                if pos != each:
                        li[each],li[pos] = li[pos],li[each]

for each in words:
        print(li)
        each = int(each)
        if each > li[9]:
                for x in range(0,9):
                        pos = x
                        if each > li[x]:
                                li[x] = each
                                for i in range(x+1,10):
                                        li[pos],li[i] = li[i],li[pos]
                                break


#Selection sort, largest-to-smallest
for each in range(0,len(li)-1):
        pos = each
        for x in range(each+1,10):
                if li[x] > li[pos]:
                        pos = x
                if pos != each:
                        li[each],li[pos] = li[pos],li[each]




print(li)
```

The code is working ALMOST the way that I want it to. I tried to create a list from the first 10 digits. Sort them, so that it in descending order. And then have python ONLY check the list, if the digits are larger than the smaller one (instead of reading through the list 10(len(x)).

This is the output I should be getting:

```
>>>[9932, 9885, 9779, 9689, 9682, 9600, 9590, 9449, 9366, 9081]
```

This is the output I am getting:

```
>>>[9932, 9689, 9885, 9779, 9682, 9025, 9600, 8949, 8612, 8575]
```

Comment: Do you **really need** to sort the whole list? Or you just need at the end the top 10 numbers?

Comment: I guess I only need the top 10.

Comment: probably your teacher will prefer 4-character indentation instead of 8

Comment: @SethRainerKania did you see the selection sort algorithm I posted on your previous question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you only need the 10 top numbers, and don't care to sort the whole list.

And if *"must try to use as little python functions as possible"* means that you (or your theacher)  prefer to to avoid `heapq`.

Another way could be to keep track of the 10 top numbers while you parse the whole file only one time:

```
top = []

with open('numbers.txt') as f:

    # the first ten numbers are going directly in
    for line in f:
        top.add(int(line.strip()))
        if len(top) == 10:
            break

    for line in f:
        num = int(line.strip())
        min_top = min(top)
        if num > min_top:    # check if the new number is a top one
            top.remove(min_top)
            top.append(num)

print(sorted(top))
```

**Update:** If you don't really need an in-place sort and since you're going to sort only 10 numebrs, I'd avoid the pain of reordering.

I'd just build a new list, example:

```
sorted_top = []
while top:
    max_top = max(top)
    sorted_top.append(max_top)
    top.remove(max_top)
```

Comment: Rik, thank you for responding. Your method has worked as much as I would like it to, however - there is some problem with the selection sort in the code I listed above. I don't want to use python's sorted(), would you mind taking a glance at that and offer any suggestions? Its missing up taking what should be li[7] and puts it in li[9]. And li[2] and li[3] are flipped from where they should be.

Comment: @Seth: Since you have only 10 numbers there's really no need for an in-place sorting algorithm, so unless it's a specific requirement. I'd suggest you to build a shine new one :) I've updated my answer.

Comment: Wow Rik. As a CS student, I think you've taught me more about thinking outside the box than I have learned this year. I appreciate your help.

We went over selection sort, insertion, and binary search Jan 25, so I was trying to master it. However, even copying the professors code verbatim, it was giving me the same answer. I feel asking him directly would be the best way to find whats wrong.

Answer (score 3):

well, by both reading in the entire file and splitting it, then using `map()`, you are keeping a lot of data in memory.

As Adrien pointed out, files are iterators in py3k, so you can just use a generator literal to provide the iterable for `nlargest`:

```
nums = (int(x) for x in open(sys.argv[1]))
```

then, using

```
heapq.nlargest(10, nums)
```

should get you what you need, and you haven't stored the entire list even once.

the program is even shorter than the original, as well!

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from heapq import nlargest
import sys

nums = (int(x) for x in open(sys.argv[1]))

print(nlargest(10, nums))
```

Comment: in python3, files are iterator: you can directly write `(int(x) for x in open('myfile.txt'))`, this will behave the same as your code.

Comment: I appreciate your response, however, I used that section of the code merely to find the correct answer. I am not confident that my professor will give credit for using a pre-solved python method, so I am going to submit both methods (python function, and my own).

Comment: @AdrienPlisson, do you know if the file is closed correctly in this case?  iow, should it say `with open('myfile') as f: nums = (...)` instead?

Comment: @PaulWoolcock: i never observed any leak when using a file this way. it relies on the garbage collector to close the file when the file object is no more referenced. (but i may be proven wrong by someone more knowledgeable on this subject...)

Comment: Better to use `with`, not all Python implementations garbage collect immediately.